# Что значит "Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on"

Tags: python, pycharm

В PyCharm в Console при работе дебагера выдается следующая строка
`Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.`
В интеренете пишут, что это связанно с `Matplotlib`, но конкретно нет никаких предложений.
Что это значит и как от него избавиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это напоминание о том, что это TkAgg интерактивный бэкэнд, что довольно удобно
Чтобы активизировать эту возможность нужно в Console PyCharm выполнить следующие команды:

```
from matplotlib import pylab
import numpy as np
%pylab
```

После чего можно поэкспериментировать

```
x = np.random.randn(10000)
plot(x.cumsum())
```

или

```
x = np.random.randn(10000)
hist(x, 100)
```

Comment: Ваш ответ не проверял на работоспособность (уже не актуально), но спасибо, может кому еще пригодится.